# C++ universal identifier different from all element in the set

Tags: c++, graph

I'm writing some kind of graph algorithm. It should be able to support all vertex identifier types that are `std::is_default_constructible<T> && std::three_way_comparable<T>` (But the main use cases are `int32_t`, `int64_t`, `std::string` and `std::string_view`, I don't think there will be many other use cases)

To get to the point, the algorithm needs to add supersource or supersink vertex to the graph, which **must be different from all vertices present in the graph**.

ex) Let `DirectedGraph<int> g` be a graph, with vertices set is given by `{1, 3, 2, 5, 6}`. Any int which is not in the vertices set will be fine. If `g` is `DirectedGraph<std::string>`, and vertices are {`"US", "China", "Japan", "Korea"}`, then anything like `"supersource"`, `"USUS"` will be fine

Is there a simple way to provide an identifier different from all existing vertices? Just supporting integer types and string types will be probably okay.

Comment: @user17732522 Let ```DirectedGraph<int> g``` be a graph, with vertices set is given by ```{1, 3, 2, 5, 6}```. Any ```int``` which is not in the vertices set will be fine. If ```g``` is ```DirectedGraph<std::string>```, and vertices are ```{"US", "China", "Japan", "Korea"}```, then anything like ```"supersource"```, ```"USUS"``` will be fine

Comment: ```std::optional``` is not comparable. Also, elaborated the example

Comment: I can't really imagine how this is supposed to work. What do you do when a new vertex is added and it happens to have this universal identifier?

Comment: That temporary universal identifier  vertex will be removed when the algorithm is finished

Comment: I am still not sure I really see the purpose, but you can simply randomly generate an identifier. Assuming the type isn't a small one (e.g. `uint8_t` or `uint16_t`) it will likely not be used yet. Look it up in whatever map you use to collect the identifiers. If it is already in there repeat the randomization.

Comment: It would be much simpler if you compared vertices by their addresses instead of identifiers.

Comment: @user17732522 Great, this should be a correct way, I'll find some cheap way to generate random strings

Comment: You will need a fallback though if the entropy isn't sufficiently large, otherwise this can easily get stuck.

Comment: `std::optional` is a perfect tool for this.  You check if the optional has a value, and if it does then you just do your comparison by "dereferencing" the optional (`*lhs op *rhs`).  If it is empty, that is your unique sentinel value.

Comment: @NathanOliver If I use ```std::optional``` I should create a new, different graph with type ```DirectedGraph<std::optional<T>>``` and I have to clone all vertices and existing edges from the original graph

Comment: The `set` is ordered. Just pick the last element and increment it or add a character, and you have a new unique element. (Until someone else attempts to add that element, of course.)